# javascript: access elements within a table

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript. I have this sample table. I want to be able to get the "http://www.msn.com" but haven't been able to do so. How should I do this?

thanx in advance

j

```
<body>
    <div id="tableContainer">
        <table width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="16%" >  </th >
                    <th width="62%"> Otras acciones</th >
                    <th class="sort" width="2%"> Código certificado</th>
                    <th class="sort" > Descripción</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                <tr>
                    <td class="iconos" >  
                        <span class="sigAccion">                
                            <a href="#" class="sigIcnHref" title="Duplicar" />
                            <span class=" btnDuplicar">
                            </span></a>
                            <a href="http://www.msn.com" class="sigIcnHref" title="Modificar" />
                           <span class=" btnModificar">
                            </span></a>
                            </span> </td>   
              <td  class="AccionRegistro">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >Docència </a></li>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >Matrícula(S) </a></li>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >Plans(1) </a></li>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >Professors(1)  </a></li>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >Horaris(9)  </a></li>
                  <li>
                  <a href="#" >HorarisProfessors(1) </a></li>
                </ul></td> 
              <td > <sup>2</sup>CAMD</td>
              <td> Cert. Alumno Matriculado Ext.</td>
            </tr>          
            </tbody>  
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

straight javascript is pretty easy.

grab a reference to a known element above the `a` element higher up the tree
get a list of `a` elements under the known element
match the `href` property to the value you know

```
var anchor = null;
var container;
var items;

container = document.getElementById('tableContainer');
items = container.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
    if (items[j].href === 'http://www.msn.com') {
        anchor = items[j];
        break;
    }
}
```

it would be better if you could directly reference the `table` element and then get a list of `a` elements from there, but if that's the only `table` in `tableContainer` it's fine.

for checking the `href` property for a known value, i usually go with a case-insensitive regex but this should be fine for your case.

Comment: I think I got it. I made a couple of changes to your answer but still it did send me in the direction I wanted to go in the first place. thanx!                  

                  var href;
                  var links = document.links;
                  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                    if (links[i].title == 'Modificar') {
                        href = links[i].href;
                        alert("Link no." + i +": " + href);
                    }
                  }

Answer (score 0):

Using a framework like jQuery it's pretty simple:

```
var href = $('#tableContainer .iconos a[title=Modificar]').attr('href');
```

Using plain Javascript it's more complicated if you can't simply add an id to the element to make it easier to locate it. You can for example look through all links in the page:

```
var href;
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  if (links[i].title == 'Modificar') href = links[i].href;
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you don't like, it can't improve the answer.

Comment: is it acceptable to use `document.links`? things like `document.forms` are generally discouraged.

Comment: an my answer you complain about the usage of frameworks and here you complain about the usage of a generic JS functionality? OK, document.links is not very good as it selects every link and not only those within the table. But it is not always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this by using jQuery

```
$('#tableContainer a').each(function() {    
    if (this.href == 'http://www.msn.com'){
           // Do something like  $(this).hide(); 
    }
    else {
       // Do somthing like $(this).show();

          }
        });
```

here is an example of [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/7cnQN/94/)

Answer (score -1):

If the structure is always like this, a code for Prototype would look like this:

```
var allLinks = $$('#tableConatiner tbody tr td span a');
var msnLInk = allLinks[1].href;
```

You can also use jQuery with a similar selector or even pure JS which will need some additional selections. But using an id attribute (e.g. "msnLink") you can get it using a direct selection:

```
var msnLink = $('msnLink').href;
```

I can you extend the code with an ID?

**EDIT**: If the title or class is unique and always the same you can also use one of the following lines:

```
var msnLink = $$('a[class="sigIcnHref"]').first().href;
var msnLink = $$('a[title="Modificar"]').first().href;
```

Can you give us some more information about the structure and what you want to do with the element after selecting it?

Comment: The idea would be that the first column could have 1-3 buttons. When it has one, it should take the link associated to it and assign it to the whole row so you can click on it and it would do the same thing as if you'd click on the button directly.

I know how to assign a given address to the whole row, but the thing is that the one I need to get is the one inside these buttons.

I'd like to know if it's possible just using javascript, no html mod and no jquery as these options would require major modifications to the code.

thanx

Comment: nobody mentioned using prototype or jquery. libraries should not be assumed.

Comment: Nobody either mentioned not to use them. He mentioned that he is new to JS so giving him the advice to pick a framework like Prototype or jQuery IS a good idea. His comment that he doesn't want to take any framework was given after I posted my answer. So where is the problem with my answer?

Comment: so all option not mentioned by the OP should be assumed as fair game? why not tell him to build a flash applet that scrapes the page for him? i made my comment before reading javier's. if you want to suggest a framework, a comment on the question would be a good place to do it. and concerning my comment about `document.links`, i haven't ever seen that used and was asking about appropriateness of that, with no criticism implied.

Comment: @lincolnk: Ah so then you would not recommend someone a IDE to someone as there is something like notepad? Giving someone a hint on how to make his programming in a new programming language easier is a bad idea? And flash has so much to do with selecting elements from the DOM. Please don't try to argue your downvote with such arguments.